# Does bounty create a perverse incentive to not answer a question immediately?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Does putting a bounty on a question create a perverse incentive for others to hold off on answering the questing right away (if they see the question) and wait for a bounty to be offered?

I suspect there is a way to see the effects of 'bounty' feature by looking at how long a question waits before being answered on average. It might not be easy to account for other factors but a general 'wait time' might give some insights. I wonder if those who run Stack Overflow have this information.

Comment: Why don't you give it a go your self: http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial

Comment: Makes no sense, only ~0.6% of the questions are bountied.  The odds that "waiting" turns into anything useful are far too low.

Comment: No, because this is the Internet and [everyone wants to be first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533).

Comment: To elaborate, there is in fact a completely opposite effect [meta-tag:fastest-gun] that is much more significant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only a tiny number of questions get bountied.

Waiting for a bounties to be offered in questions you have good answers to is a horrible strategy, since it's very unlikely the OP will post a bounty just because you are taking a bit long in posting an answer. And you have no way of knowing who is going to be willing to post a bounty.

If you try this out, the more likely scenario is that someone else is going to post an answer before you do. Not necessarily a bad thing for your hypothetical answer; since maybe it is much better than the one the quicker shooter posted and could end up getting more up-votes than the first-posted in the long-term.

Considering all this, the "delay incentive" you imagine doesn't really work or happens.

If you want to make rep out of bounties, you can simply look for bountied questions in tags you are competent, which is what a lot of people do. Even if you do not get the bounty, the additional attention that a bounty generates might end up being good for your answer in terms of votes.

Regarding stats you are thinking about, you play with the data and can check most of them using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial). Have fun!